# No se insertan entidades en una tabla de 3 ID Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, eclipse, jpa

Estoy con un proyecto con varias clases, entre ellas Profesor, Coche y Llave, de una autoescuela. Un profesor puede tener varias llaves pero una llave solo pertenece a un profesor y solo abre un coche, un coche puede tener muchas llaves que lo abran y muchos profesores que lo usen, por lo que la llave solo tiene un profesor y solo abre un coche. Para ello creo una clase profesoresCochesLlavesId, que consiste en coger la id de cada uno y crear con ellas un objeto de esa clase que sirva de id, para la clase profesoresCochesLlaves, la cual tiene una entidad de profesor, coche y llave. Al ejecutar, se insertan los coches, los profesores y las llaves en sus respectivas tablas, pero no en la tabla profesoresCochesLlaves y no descubro por qué.
He de añadir que no da ningún mensaje de error y la tabla profesoresCochesLlaves se crea pero no inserta nada.

Código de Coche:

```
package principal.modelo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Coches")
public class Coche {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="Matricula")
    private String matricula;
    
    @Column(name="Modelo")
    private String modelo;
    
    @Column(name="Marca")
    private String marca;
    
    @Column(name="FechaITV")
    private Date fechaITV;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "coche", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Alumno> alumnos;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "llave", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> llaves;
    

    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> profesores;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public Coche() {
        alumnos=new HashSet<Alumno>();
        profesores=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        llaves=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        
    }


    public Coche(String matricula, String modelo, String marca) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.marca = marca;
        alumnos=new HashSet<Alumno>();
        profesores=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        llaves=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
    }
    
    public void addLlave(Profesor p, Llave l) {
        ProfesoresCochesLlaves pc=new ProfesoresCochesLlaves(p,this,l);
        if(llaves.contains(pc)) {
            llaves.remove(pc);
        }
        llaves.add(pc);
        p.getLlaves().add(pc);
        p.getCoches().add(pc);
    }
    
    
    //getters setters
    
    
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    


    public Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> getLlaves() {
        return llaves;
    }


    public void setLlaves(Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> llaves) {
        this.llaves = llaves;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public Date getFechaITV() {
        return fechaITV;
    }
    public void setFechaITV(Date fechaITV) {
        this.fechaITV = fechaITV;
    }
    public Set<Alumno> getAlumnos() {
        return alumnos;
    }
    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public void setAlumnos(Set<Alumno> alumnos) {
        this.alumnos = alumnos;
    }
    public Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> getProfesores() {
        return profesores;
    }
    public void setProfesores(Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> profesores) {
        this.profesores = profesores;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coche [id=" + id + ", matricula=" + matricula + ", modelo=" + modelo + ", marca=" + marca
                + ", fechaITV=" + fechaITV + ", alumnos=" + alumnos + ", profesores=" + profesores + "]";
    }



    
    
    
    

}
```

Código de profesor:

```
package principal.modelo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Profesores")
public class Profesor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    

    @Column(name="DNI")
    private String dni;
    

    @Column(name="Nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name="Apellidos")
    private String apellidos;


    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Alumno> alumnos;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "llave", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> llaves;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "coche", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> coches;

    public Profesor() {
        alumnos = new HashSet<Alumno>();
        coches = new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        llaves=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
    }

    
    
    

    public Profesor(String dni, String nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        alumnos = new HashSet<Alumno>();
        coches = new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        llaves=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
    }





    public Profesor(Integer id, String dni, String nombre, String apellidos, Set<Alumno> alumnos, Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> coches) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        alumnos = new HashSet<Alumno>();
        coches = new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
        llaves=new HashSet<ProfesoresCochesLlaves>();
    }

    
    public void addCoche(Coche c, Llave l) {
        ProfesoresCochesLlaves pc=new ProfesoresCochesLlaves(this,c,l);
        if(coches.contains(pc)) {
            coches.remove(pc);
        }
        coches.add(pc);
        c.getProfesores().add(pc);
        c.getLlaves().add(pc);
            
    }
    
    
    // getters y setters

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Set<Alumno> getAlumnos() {
        return alumnos;
    }

    public void setAlumnos(Set<Alumno> alumnos) {
        this.alumnos = alumnos;
    }

    public Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> getCoches() {
        return coches;
    }

    public void setCoches(Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> coches) {
        this.coches = coches;
    }
    

    public Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> getLlaves() {
        return llaves;
    }





    public void setLlaves(Set<ProfesoresCochesLlaves> llaves) {
        this.llaves = llaves;
    }





    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profesor [id=" + id + ", dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", alumnos="
                + alumnos + ", coches=" + coches + "]";
    }

    
    
    
    

}
```

Código de llave:

```
package principal.modelo;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="llave")
public class Llave {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="profesor_id", nullable=false)
    private Profesor profesor;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "coche_id", nullable = false)
    private Coche coche;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Profesor getProfesor() {
        return profesor;
    }

    public void setProfesor(Profesor profesor) {
        this.profesor = profesor;
    }

    public Coche getCoche() {
        return coche;
    }

    public void setCoche(Coche coche) {
        this.coche = coche;
    }

    public Llave(Profesor profesor, Coche coche) {
        this.profesor = profesor;
        this.coche = coche;
    }

    public Llave() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Llave [id=" + id + ", profesor=" + profesor + ", coche=" + coche + "]";
    }

    
    
}
```

Código de ProfesoresCochesLlavesId:

```
package principal.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class ProfesoresCochesLlavesId implements Serializable{
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="profesor_id")
    private Integer profesorId;
    
    @Column(name="coche_id")
    private Integer cocheId;
    
    @Column(name="llave_id")
    private Integer llaveId;

    public ProfesoresCochesLlavesId() {
        super();
    }

    public ProfesoresCochesLlavesId(Integer idP, Integer idC, Integer idL) {
        this.profesorId = idP;
        this.cocheId = idC;
        this.cocheId=idL;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o==null || getClass() !=o.getClass()) { 
            return false;
        }
        ProfesoresCochesLlavesId that=(ProfesoresCochesLlavesId) o;
        return Objects.equals(profesorId, that.profesorId) && Objects.equals(cocheId, that.cocheId) && Objects.equals(llaveId, that.llaveId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(cocheId, profesorId, llaveId);
    }

    public Integer getProfesorId() {
        return profesorId;
    }

    public void setProfesorId(Integer profesorId) {
        this.profesorId = profesorId;
    }

    public Integer getCocheId() {
        return cocheId;
    }

    public void setCocheId(Integer cocheId) {
        this.cocheId = cocheId;
    }
    

    public Integer getLlaveId() {
        return llaveId;
    }

    public void setLlaveId(Integer llaveId) {
        this.llaveId = llaveId;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Código de profesoresCochesLlaves:

```
package principal.modelo;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="profesores_coches_llaves")
public class ProfesoresCochesLlaves {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProfesoresCochesLlavesId id=new ProfesoresCochesLlavesId();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("profesor_id")
    private Profesor profesor;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("coche_id")
    private Coche coche;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("llave_id")
    private Llave llave;
    

    public ProfesoresCochesLlaves() {
        
    }

    public ProfesoresCochesLlaves(Profesor p, Coche c, Llave l) {
        this.coche=c;
        this.profesor=p;
        this.llave=l;
        this.id=new ProfesoresCochesLlavesId(p.getId(), c.getId(),l.getId());
}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o==null || getClass() !=o.getClass()) { 
            return false;
        }
        ProfesoresCochesLlaves that=(ProfesoresCochesLlaves) o;
        return Objects.equals(coche, that.coche) && Objects.equals(profesor, that.profesor) && Objects.equals(llave, that.llave);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(profesor, coche, llave);
    }
    public ProfesoresCochesLlavesId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ProfesoresCochesLlavesId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Profesor getProfesor() {
        return profesor;
    }

    public void setProfesor(Profesor profesor) {
        this.profesor = profesor;
    }

    public Coche getCoche() {
        return coche;
    }

    public void setCoche(Coche coche) {
        this.coche = coche;
    }

    public Llave getLlave() {
        return llave;
    }

    public void setLlave(Llave llave) {
        this.llave = llave;
    }
    


    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Añado el código de la clase Alumno por si fuera de utilidad:

```
package principal.modelo;

import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Alumnos")
public class Alumno {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="DNI")
    private String dni;
    
    @Column(name="Nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name="Apellidos")
    private String apellidos;
    
    @Column (name="Notas")
    private String notas;
    
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="id_profesor", nullable = false)
    private Profesor profesor;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_Coche", nullable = false)
    private Coche coche;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    


public Alumno() {
        profesor=new Profesor();
        coche=new Coche();
    }

public Alumno(String nombre, String dni) {
        
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dni = dni;
        profesor=new Profesor();
        coche=new Coche();
    }





    

//getters setters



    public Alumno(Integer id, String dni, String nombre, String apellidos, String notas, Profesor profesor, Coche coche) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.notas = notas;
    this.profesor = new Profesor();
    this.coche = new Coche();
}

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    

    public String getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(String notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Profesor getProfesor() {
        return profesor;
    }

    public void setProfesor(Profesor profesor) {
        this.profesor = profesor;
    }

    public Coche getCoche() {
        return coche;
    }

    public void setCoche(Coche coche) {
        this.coche = coche;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [id=" + id + ", dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", profesor="
                + profesor + ", coche=" + coche + "]";
    }
    
    

    
}
```

Código del main (el método que ejecuta todo es el crearTablas()):

```
package principal.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import principal.modelo.Alumno;
import principal.modelo.Coche;
import principal.modelo.Llave;
import principal.modelo.Profesor;
import principal.modelo.Rol;
import principal.modelo.Usuario;
import principal.persistencia.RolRepo;
import principal.servicio.implementacion.AlumnoServiceImpl;
import principal.servicio.implementacion.CocheServiceImpl;
import principal.servicio.implementacion.LlaveServiceImpl;
import principal.servicio.implementacion.ProfesorServiceImpl;
import principal.servicio.implementacion.UsuarioServiceImpl;


@Controller
public class WebController {
    
    @Autowired
    AlumnoServiceImpl alumnoService;
    
    @Autowired 
    ProfesorServiceImpl profeService;
    
    @Autowired
    CocheServiceImpl cocheService;
    
    @Autowired
    LlaveServiceImpl llaveService;
    
    @Autowired
    UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioService;
    
    @Autowired
    RolRepo rolRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    String home() {
        
        crearTablas();
         
        return "index";
            
    }
    

    @GetMapping("/l")
    String homealumnos() {
         
        return "alumnos";
            
    }
    private void crearTablas() {
        
        Alumno a1 = new Alumno("Alba", "541245F");
        Profesor p1 = new Profesor("Pedro", "4529L");
        Coche c1 = new Coche("5894 GHL", "2023", "Peugeot");
        Alumno a2 = new Alumno("David", "45446G");
        Profesor p2 = new Profesor("Alejandro", "4515K");
        Coche c2 = new Coche("5894 DSF", "2021", "Seat");
        Rol rolBasico = new Rol("ROLE_USER");
        Rol rolAdmin = new Rol("ROLE_ADMIN");
        Llave llave1=new Llave();
        Llave llave2=new Llave();
        Usuario usuarioAdmin = new Usuario("admin", "admin", "$2a$12$jcd/P/f86nT9YXQbx/3tJeQye8h0aMhNm6EzzKkZMNLUCtIxpTNJa");
        usuarioAdmin.getRoles().add(rolAdmin);

        /*
         * LocalDate fecha=LocalDate.of(2024, 5, 13); c1.setFechaITV(fecha);
         */
        Date fecha = new Date(125, 6, 23);
        c1.setFechaITV(fecha);

        a1.setProfesor(p1);
        p1.getAlumnos().add(a1);
        a1.setCoche(c1);
        c1.getAlumnos().add(a1);
        llave1.setCoche(c1);
        llave1.setProfesor(p1);
        
        
        //c1.getProfesores().add(p1);
        
        a2.setProfesor(p2);
        p2.getAlumnos().add(a2);
        a2.setCoche(c2);
        c2.getAlumnos().add(a2);
        c2.addLlave(p2,llave2);
        llave2.setCoche(c2);
        llave2.setProfesor(p2);
        
        p2.addCoche(c2, llave2);
        //c2.getProfesores().add(p2);

        /*RolRepo rolRepo = new RolRepo();
        UsuarioRepo usuarioRepo = new UsuarioRepo();
        AlumnoRepo alumnoRepo = new AlumnoRepo();
        ProfesorRepo profesorRepo = new ProfesorRepo();
        CocheRepo cocheRepo = new CocheRepo();*/
        
        //usuarioService.insertarUsuario(usuarioAdmin);
        //rolRepo.save(rolAdmin);
        //rolRepo.save(rolBasico);
        cocheService.insertarCoche(c1);
        cocheService.insertarCoche(c2);
        
        
        profeService.insertarProfesor(p1);
        profeService.insertarProfesor(p2);
        
        alumnoService.insertarAlumno(a1);
        alumnoService.insertarAlumno(a2);
        
        llaveService.insertarLlave(llave1);
        llaveService.insertarLlave(llave2);
        
        c1.addLlave(p1,llave1); //el metodo addLlave tambien añade la llave al profesor
        p1.addCoche(c1, llave1);
        

    }
}
```

Comment: La entidad *llave* no debe tener relacion *OneToOne* con *profesor* sino *onetomany* con ProfesorCochesLlave*. Ahora, esta última no registra en la base de datos porque nunca la creas. No veo un New PrifwsoresCochesLlaves ni un add de esta a alguna de las clases que tiene una relación OneToMany con esta.

Comment: Perdón, la clase ProfesorCochesLlaves debería ser una entidad independiente con ID única. Como embebida tendrás muchos problemas. Mejor que tengas una relación unoamuchos que tener 3 id's. Por otro lado tendrías que incorporar el nombre de esta tabla en los Join para que sepa a través de cual tiene la relación y quitar toda referencia de esta y tener ManyToMany

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich El embebida es un requisito que tengo que cumplir por ahora, así que no podría descartarla, el nombre de la tabla mediante el Join tiene que ser sobre algún atributo en particular?, porque no sabría definir uno que sea mas esencial que otros

Comment: Por lo que veo es que quieres que la tabla *profesor_cocje_llave" sea un *join table" de las 3 entidades. No sé si *@JoinTable* puedas utilizarlo como tal, es decir, un *ManyToManyToMany* ya que tu clave principal es de esas 3. Te sugiero que revises tu modelo: por ejemplo, la clase profesor tiene OnToMany para llaves y OneToMany para Coches. Pero la llave ya tiene el coche. Una llave abre a un solo coche. Por lo tanto es uno a uno. Si el profesor tiene una o mss llaves entonces implícitamente tiene  uno o mas coches. No necesita entonces la relación hacia coches.

Comment: Llaves, coches y profesores son entidades primarias me parece y tu tabla Profesores_coches_llaves debería actuar como independiente a ellas colo una entidad "Asignacion" donde es la que registra los 3 datos. Pero la tratas en tu aplicaci9n como una entida con su conttoladoe

Comment: Por otro lado dices un coche puede tener varias llaves, por lo tanto. varias llaves abren un coche medio que contradice una llave un coche, bueno pueden ser copias. En todo caso tu tabla con losn3 id debería ser algo como una tabla de movimiento, con sus propios atributos, porque no me imaginonque varios profesores tengan llaves del mismo coche sin que no haya de por medio un horario porque ambos no pueden utilizar el coche al mismo tiempo

Comment: En todo caso, tu única relación ManyToMany es Profesor-Llave, el coche es único , puede tener varias llaves pero es un solo coche. Si coche tiene @OnToMany a Llaves, entonces, puedes saber a cuantos profesores se le ha asignado el coche. Llave tiene una relación ManyToOne a Coche y Profesor tiene ManyToMany a Llave. Por lo tanto tu tabla Join ManyToMany debería ser Profesor-Llave, sin incluir el coche porque está implícito en la llave. Salvo que tenga un coche sin  llave y llave sin coche. Aunque ni eso, el profesor solo un UnoMuchos a Llave porque las duplicadas se registra con propio código.